# How to put generated files (e.g. object files) into a separate folder when using Qt/qmake?

Tags: qt, qmake, object-files

I have a Qt project that uses qmake. To improve clarity and readability, I'd like to keep the

- source files
- build system
- generated files (such as object files)

separate.

So my first step was putting the source files into a src/ sub directory:

```
myproject/
    myproject.pro
    src/
        main.cpp
        MainWindow.ui
        ...
```

That way I separated the source files from the build system (*.pro). However, when I then run `qmake` followed by `make`, the generated files (object files, etc) are placed into the main project folder:

```
myproject/
    myproject.pro
    Makefile
    main.o
    ui_MainWindow.h
    ...
    src/
        main.cpp
        MainWindow.ui
        ...
```

Well, at least they weren't put into the `src/` folder, but how do I specify that they are put into another sub folder such as `build/`?

```
myproject/
    myproject.pro
    Makefile
    build/
        main.o
        ui_MainWindow.h
        ...
    src/
        main.cpp
        MainWindow.ui
        ...
```

(BTW, I don't care where the target binary `myproject` is put, but I guess it should be placed directly into project folder rather than into `build/`.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can add the following lines to your `*.pro` file:

```
DESTDIR=bin #Target file directory
OBJECTS_DIR=generated_files #Intermediate object files directory
MOC_DIR=generated_files #Intermediate moc files directory
```

A list of variables is available at the following locations:

- [Qt 4.8](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html)
- [Qt 5](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html)

Comment: It works for me.  Note however that the following don't seem to work as a way to use the root of the build directory:
DESTDIR=  #doesn't work
DESTDIR=.  #doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

https://wiki.qt.io/Undocumented_QMake#Config_features

> object_with_source — outputs each object file into the same directory as its source file (replaced by object_parallel_to_source in the latest versions).
>   object_parallel_to_source — recreate source folder tree for object files (replaces object_with_source).

in *.pro write

```
CONFIG += object_parallel_to_source
```

Comment: Nothing change!