# Organize Visual Studio and Qt Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

How can one organize their Visual Studio and Qt project such that we have a folder structure similar to this:

```
project/
  src/
    main.h
    main.cpp
    project.pro
  vs/
    debug/
      debug stuff...
    release/
      release stuff...
    project.sln
    project.vcxproj
    project.vcxproj.filters
```

When I first create a project, I make the Qt project file using:

```
qmake -project
```

And then I create the Visual Studio project:

```
qmake -tp vc project.pro
```

But this creates everything in the same directory, and that's just really nasty. I'm open to better organization suggestions as well.

**Update:** More details why I need help. When I try to compile the project using this structure, Visual Studio complains that the `MOC` can't find the project headers.

**Build output:**

```
1>  MOC main.h
1>  moc: main.h: No such file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(170,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440387/how-to-put-generated-files-e-g-object-files-into-a-separate-folder-when-using/23007090#23007090) links to a Qt help page about pro-commands which lets you specify some of the directory settings you want to achieve

Comment: This would be relatively easy to do with CMake.