# Change building directory in .pro

Tags: c++, qt, projects-and-solutions

How can i change building directory in qt project file? I tried this:

```
TARGET = project
win32: {
    CONFIG(release, debug|release): DLLDESTDIR +=  $$PWD/../lib
}
unix: {
    CONFIG(release, debug|release): QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote(cp project $$PWD/../lib)
}
```

But this didn't give result :(

Found something a bit similar: `DESTDIR` parameter. However, this option is only responsible for executables. And how to transfer all the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @BNT for the help.

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
  DESTDIR = $$PWD/../debug/lib
} else {
  DESTDIR = $$PWD/../lib
}

OBJECTS_DIR = $${DESTDIR}/.obj
MOC_DIR = $${DESTDIR}/.moc
RCC_DIR = $${DESTDIR}/.rcc
UI_DIR = $${DESTDIR}/.ui
```

Where `DESTDIR` is the folder for the executable.

But the Makefile in such a way not to move. It has a dedicated constant, and in the documentation, as @BNT already noticed, it is written:

> Note: Do not attempt to overwrite the value of this variable.

Answer (score 1):

While QtCreator has one [single setting](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-build-settings.html) for the generated output, in order to achieve the same with `qmake` you have to specify [some more variables](https://forum.qt.io/topic/33803/solved-qt-creator-how-to-refer-to-the-build-directory-path-in-a-pro-file/3), look at the ones ending in `DIR` specified in the [qmake variables overview](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html).

I you can get a good overview from [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23007090/7926064) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2583548/7926064) as well.

UPDATE: never tried this but give `$$OUT_PWD` a try as mentioned in the first blogpost.

UPDATE2: never mind, the [docs state](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#out-pwd) `Note: Do not attempt to overwrite the value of this variable.`